# Handling multiple objects in Java

Tags: java, object, multiple-instances

I'm creating a game in which the player (the **Player object**) must fight many zombies (the **Zombie object**). The fight is simulated, but the user can set up defenses between fighting periods.

I want an *efficient* way to handle all of the zombies. Each Zombie object has attributes such as health and attack that are effected and take an affect on the Player object's attack and health, respectively. When the player attacks a specific zombie with a weapon, I want to be able to execute `specificZombie.health -= 20;`.

My problem is that I don't know how to handle tens or maybe hundreds of Zombie objects, each acting individually with their individual attributes and individual methods such as attack() or move(). Nor do I know how to effectively initialize all of the Zombies while still being able to call on specific ones. I understand that I can use a loop, but then how do I name all of the zombies so that they can individually be called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put them in a list or array, then iterate through the list/array.  Each zombie can be identified by the index of the list or array.

Array:

```
Zombie[] zombieArray = new Zombie[10];
for(int x=0; x<10; x++){
    Zombie z = new Zombie(--whatever your parameters are);
    zombieArray[x] = z;
}
```

List:

```
List<Zombie> zombieList = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int x=0; x<10; x++){
        Zombie z = new Zombie(--whatever your paremeters are);
        zombieList.add(z);
    }
```

Comment: I don't know why an array or ArrayList didn't even cross my mind. I'll be using this method. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> My problem is that I don't know how to handle tens or maybe hundreds
>   of Zombie objects, each acting individually with their individual
>   attributes and individual methods such as attack() or move(). Nor do I
>   know how to effectively initialize all of the Zombies while still
>   being able to call on specific ones.

=> you need to declare an `interface`, but at least an `abstract class` Zombie. 
Than at implementation you will have a RapidAttackZombie , a SlowRunningZombie, which expends your parent class. Highly suggest to read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) page.

Because those has a common class, than you can put into any storing collection: Array, ArrayList, Hashtable, whatever you need.

At implemetation you will implement / override attack() and move(), which should be declared as abstract at abstract class, or can have a default implementation.

Initialization of zombies depends your level editor engine output result, aka you have to dectlare: atposition X I want a ZombieType1, at position y,z I want ZombieType2 and so on.

it is not 10 minutes how to dvelop a full game,  I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Better have a data structure like

```
Map<String,List<zombieClass>>
```

In String part you can store your zombie name or probably type. Inside you map use a list(ArrayList) to hold various zombies. In array you would have resizing constraints whereas in ArrayList it would be dynamic and can be modified at runtime. In the List you can actually have your ZombieClass.

```
public class ZombieClass{
   private float health;
   private float damageCapability;
   //getters ans setters
}
```

Comment: I'm somewhat new to these concepts of programming, so can you explain what Map<String,List<zombieClas>> is?

Comment: It is a data structure.Map is a key-value pair data structure. So you have a Map whose key is of type String and value is of type List.List a data structure whose size dynamically increase unlike Arrays where you specify it at the declaration phase. If you are new to these concepts better go through Collection framework in Java. You can start from [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_collections.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You create a Zombie object array or list that contains Zombies

```
Class Zombie {

     private int health ;
     private int attack;

     public boolean died(){
       if(health < 0) return true;  
     }        
}



class Game {

    public static void main(String [] arg){
      List<Zombie> zombies = new ArrayList<Zombie>();
      for(int i  =0 ;i<10; i++)  
      zombies.add(new Zombie());
    } 

    // main game loop
    public void render(){
        for(int i =0; i<10; i++){
              // get each zombie and do whatever you want
        }     
    }

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make your `Zombie` class like bellow, using [Strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern):

```
class Zombie {

   private AttackAction atackAction;
   private MoveAction moveAction;
   //other attributes of the zombie;

}
```

And your `AttackAction` and `MoveAction` interfaces are like bellow:

```
interface AttackAction {
      public void attack();
}

interface MoveAction {
      public void move();
}
```

And There can be two implementations per interface. like in case of `AttackAction`, one is `RealAttackAction` and the other is `DummyAttackAction`.

```
class RealAttackAction implements AttackAction {

     public void action(){
         //do some real action
     }
}

class DummyAttackAction implements AttackAction {

     public void action(){
         //do some dummy action
     }
}
```

And then If a zombie can attack, pass `RealAttackAction`'s reference to it, if it cannot attack, pass `DummyAttackAction`'s reference. Similar things can be done with `MoveAction` interface.

You can maintain a `list` (or `map`, if there is an unique identification to each zombie) for the zombie to handle them efficienly!

Comment: I'm new to most concepts you showed in your answer, so I don't think I'll be using them. But I'll surely look into them to expand my knowledge of programming.

Comment: I showed you, how efficiently and nicely, you can design your `Zombie` and its actions, using [Strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern). Its a GoF [Design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns), hugely used in your type of problem.

Comment: And I think you should give it a try, cause its nice to learn new exciting things like this. This knowledge will help you a lot in future!